# Is PDF capable of conditional display and, if so, how can I achieve it with pdfTeX/friends?

Tags: pdf, conditionals

Most of the time, we (or more conservatively, *I*) think of PDF as a static format fit for printing.  I've been surprised in the past at how versatile it is -- how dynamic and interactive it can be -- so I've decided to ask the following.

I'd like to create a multi-lingual document where the language can be determined at run-time.  That is, the user could select from a drop-down / radio button group to choose a language, and the relevant content would be appropriately substituted throughout the document.

If this *is* possible, my ideal interface/MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{whatever}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for \kant and \lipsum

\DeclareLanguageChoices{kant={One of Kant's Books},
                psuedo-latin={Classical gibberish used in typesetting.}}

\begin{document}
\dochoices

\begin{LanguageChoice}

\BeginLanguage{kant}
\kant
\EndLanguage{kant}

\BeginLanguage{psuedo-latin}
\lipsum
\EndLanguage{psuedo-latin}

\end{LanguageChoice}
\end{document}
```

The syntax above is LaTeX, but solutions in pdfTeX, XeTeX, ConTeXt, and LuaTeX are all most welcome; just adapt it to the format of your choice. :-)

With this syntax, the produced PDF would display some sort of control at the top (at `\dochoices`) using the display text (that which is in `{}`) and, depending on the selected key, display the appropriate content.

---

#### Thoughts on Potential Solutions

- I don't think the format can re-flow itself even vertically, so just taking the maximum box size would be necessary and sufficient.
- More as I / the comments think of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two ways to do this with PDF:

1. Layers/Optional Content Groups (OCGs). If you load the [`microtype`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/microtype) manual in Adobe Reader you will see the effects e.g. on page 4. There are LaTeX packages for this (check the [ocg](/questions/tagged/ocg) tag) and [context](/questions/tagged/context) can create them easily. Note that few viewers but Adobe Reader and Acrobat support OCGs.
2. [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). These effects can probably be achieved with JS, but few PDF viewers but Adobe's software support JavaScript.